# Tooltip in a table

Tags: tables, grid, tooltips

[image]OK, so there's a Table. And a client who wants a tooltip in that grid. To show 13 additional columns (I am not kidding), and few rows.

Please confirm, that tooltip usually shows a sentence. And a short one at that.

I need to offer an alternative. "More" button? The additional information are basically extra columns, that are just secondary in importance, to the persistent columns.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: What is the purpose of the tooltip? It seems like there's 2 things: showing additional columns, and how to make the user aware that there are more. Is that correct? Do you have a mock showing what you want to do?

Comment: Here @Mike M. User clicks on "Show more" icon, and extra content appears in the grid. First column is sticky. For navigating the rest, I added a horizontal scrollbar; I know that's less than ideal, but IMO, better than tooltip, with 13 columns. Thoughts?

Comment: I am struggling with the terminology here. The "grid" is a table and the "tooltips" seem to be buttons. Tooltips are not buttons or links, they are a css-property that triggers a tip that appears: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: No, no. Client originally wanted tooltips, but that's not an option, in my view. Nobody puts a 13-column table in a tooltip. That's crazy. So, I created an option where there is simple "Show more" button. User clicks that, and 13 extra columns are added to the table. Table=grid, yes.

Comment: is it for internal use or is it a web app for customers?

Answer (score 1):

Tooltips show a short explanatory message, definitely not a set of columns.
It wouldn't make sanse to display them that way. A show more button that displays the additional columns, as you suggest, would be the best solution. It is also the most natural one.

And a horizontal scoll should not be an issue in this case, since it is a table.

Comment: It is internal! Thank you so much. I have been struggling with this.